# Dynamic cone penetrometer (DCP) results and correlation

Tags: geology, soil

I have been [reading about DCP](http://www.lab-quip.co.uk/dynamic-cone-penetrometer-dcp) and watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UadgMNG-LWA) of how it is done (the video is not in English). But there are something things that are still unclear and I would greatly appreciate some help and clarification. I have these questions:

1. Is there a standard number of times that the hammer must be dropped?
2. What is recorded after an $x$ number of hammer drops?

   - Lat/long coordinates of where test occurred?
   - How far the metal head penetrated the ground (in cm)?
3. What happens to that data? What does it correlate with to give us the strength of the ground? What is that strength measured in?

Comment: Cone penetration testing is something most engineers learn about during their undergraduate studies, particularly those studying civil engineering. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here migrate the question to SE Engineering.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying principle of the DCP is that the rate of penetration of the cone, when driven by a standard force, is inversely related to the strength of the material as measured by, for example, the California Bearing Ratio (CBR) test. Where the pavement layers have different strengths, the boundaries between the layers can be identified and the thickness of the layers determined. A typical result is shown.

It is recommended that a reading should be taken at increments of penetration of about 10 mm. However, it is usually easier to take readings after a set number of blows. it is therefore necessary to change the number of blows between readings according to the strength of the layer being penetrated. For good quality granular subbases readings every 5 or 10 blows are normally satisfactory but for weaker sub-base layers and subgrade readings every 1 or 2 blows may be appropriate. Little difficulty is normally experienced with the penetration of most types of granular of weakly stabilised materials. It is more difficult to penetrate strongly stabilised layers, granular materials with large particles and very dense, high quality crushed stone.
The instrument has been designed for strong materials and therefore the operator should persevere with the test. Penetration rates as low as 0.5 mm/blow are acceptable but if there is no measurable penetration after 20 consecutive blows it can be assumed that the DCP will not penetrate the material. Under these circumstances a hole can be drilled through the layer using either an electric or pneumatic drill or by coring. The lower layers of the pavement can then be tested in the normal way.

Comment: When a *reading* is taken, what information is actually recorded? Is it number of hammer blows against how penetration distance in cm? Is the metric system of measurement used? or is it the imperial?